# Return value from input field with the jQuery blur function

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, return, onblur

Goal: User focuses input field. User writes a value in input field. When user is done and the input field isn't in focus anymore, save inserted value to a variable called 'inputFieldValue'. This is should be done invoking the function 'returnInputValue'.

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My test</title>  
    </head>
    <body>

        <input class="input" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
function returnInputValue() {

    var inputValue;

    $('.input').blur(function() {   

        inputValue = $('.input').val();

    });

    return inputValue;

}

var inputFieldValue = returnInputValue();
```

When I call the variable inputFieldValue variable from the console after having inserted a value and focused out again, it is still 'undefined'.

Have I missed something?

Comment: try to move `var inputValue;` outside from function

Comment: Your are doing it wrong. Move the logic into the `blur` handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you execute is an asynchronous function, i.e., it is based on the time after the `input` triggers a `blur` event. You need to either return it inside the `blur` event:

```
function returnInputValue() {
    var inputValue;
    $('.input').blur(function() {   
        inputValue = $('.input').val();
        return inputValue;
    });
}
```

As suggested by some, even above code is not correct. The `inputValue` doesn't work as it always returns `undefined`.

Or, set it up to directly access the last `blur`red value.

```
var inputValue = "Not Blurred Yet!";
$('.input').blur(function() {   
    inputValue = $('.input').val();
});

function returnInputValue() {
    return inputValue;
}
```

Comment: Your first example is wrong. The `return`statement belongs to the `blur` handler not the `returnInputValue` function. The `returnInputValue` returns `undefined` as it doesn't have a `return`ed value.

Comment: @Vohuman I have updated my answer. Can you remove the downvote?

Comment: I'd delete the first snippet and it's related information. It should be noted that defining a function and returning a predefined value doesn't make a lot of sense! I'll remove the downvote. My downvote hurt your feelings, sorry about that, but wrong information can hurt many innocent people.

Comment: @Vohuman I have clearly said that, many comments asking to include `return` inside the `blur` event, which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is the current logic:

1. Initialize a variable that has an `undefined` value.
2. Bind a handler which is executed at undefined junctures, the variable is still `undefined`.
3. Return the `undefined` value immediately

The above logic is broken and should be rectified. The best option is moving the final logic into the `blur` handler:

```
 $('.input').blur(function() {   
    var inputValue = this.value;
    // do something with the value
    // ...
 });
```

If you need to get the value at a certain juncture, query the DOM, select the element and get it's value.

Comment: The fact that my questions get downvoted for criticising an answer  makes not sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare variable outside the function

```
    <script>
       var inputValue;
        function returnInputValue() {

        $('.input').blur(function() {   

            inputValue = $('.input').val();

        });

        return inputValue;
   }
    var inputFieldValue = returnInputValue();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use.

```
$(document).on("blur","#Yourinput",function(){
   var Myval = $("#Yourinput").val();
   // Execute your code here I.e call your function 
   // ...
// You do not even have to call you function put
// It in a div to display 
$("#yourdiv").html(Myval);
//Will display it in a div
//Or add to array
Yourarray.push(Myval);
});
```

This uses jQuery `.on()` method.

This method is very flexible. If your inserting into a database you can do that here too quite simply with jquery ajax.

You have to play with the events I.e replace blur with another event but if your using jquery this I believe is the simplest method

Comment: He/she can use focus/blur to invoke his/her function

Comment: Well, that's good suggestion but you haven't provided sufficient information regarding _why_ he/she should use the suggested code snippet.

Comment: I felt displaying how to pull to value from the event should be enough. Added call function in to my answer. I'm on a phone so will tidy add further when I get infront of my laptop.

Comment: I see. This answer is on the right track and can be further improved.